# Add mailchimp subscriber via javascript alert() (sweetalert)

Tags: javascript, mailchimp, sweetalert

I am using sweet alert to display an input popup. I want to add the entered email as a mailchimp subscriber.

I have no problem with the popup, but can someone help me with the webhook or API call to add a subscriber?

I'm using this example for the input popup:

```
swal({
title: "An input!",
text: "Write something interesting:",
type: "input",
showCancelButton: true,
closeOnConfirm: false,
animation: "slide-from-top",
inputPlaceholder: "Write something" },
function(inputValue){
if (inputValue === false)
return false;
if (inputValue === "") {
 swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
 return false   }
  swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success");
 });
```

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Hope you were able to solve this, but just for the update - here is a neat way on how to do this.

Sweet alert allows for a callback on the input. Assuming you are using jquery in your project, this can be achieved like this.

```js
swal({
title: "An input!",
text: "Write something interesting:",
type: "input",
showCancelButton: true,
closeOnConfirm: false,
animation: "slide-from-top",
inputPlaceholder: "Write something" },
function(inputValue){
  if (inputValue === false)
    return false;

  if (inputValue === "") {
    swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
    return false;
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "<your-url-to-mailchimp-form-submit>",
    data: { email: inputValue },
    type: "POST"
  }).done(function(data) {
    swal("Woohoo!", "You have subscribed to our mailing list", "success");
  }).error(function(data) {
    swal.showInputError("Ohh no, something went wrong.");
  });

});
```

You can also evaluate the reply you get in the 'data' variable from mailchimp to display the message correctly.